# send query results in email on condition

Tags: sql-server-2008, email

I would like to send the results of a query via email and it works fine but I need to only execute the email if the results is not null.

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='GDB Admin',
    @recipients = 'joe@mail.com',
    @subject = 'GDB Warning - THIS IS A TEST',
    @body ='Key',
    @query =  'select clientkey as apikey, ImportDate from 
 QueryDData.dbo.QueryData   where clientkey not in(''blablablabla'')'
```

so if clientkey is empty do not send the email

Answer (score 0):

ok figured this out by first executing the query and assigning results to a variable and if the variable was not null then execute the above email process.